# Layout with display:table to take body height

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, transition

I am trying to make a layout with display:table (as it seems that's the best way to achieve equal coloumns).

Here is a fiddle which goes closely to what I want:
**http://jsfiddle.net/elvista/ATWR3/**

The requirements:

- Sidebar and Content should have equal height (achieved)
- Sidebar is fixed width, Content is fluid (**doesn't seem to work**).
- Footer should be placed inside content and stickied at the bottom (achieved)
- In case both content and sidebar doesn't have content, the #wrapper should take up the same height as body (**possible with CSS?**)

Some pointers in any of these two problems would be appreciated.

```
Here is a fiddle which goes closely to what I want:
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/elvista/ATWR3/**

Comment: have you tried to use give a  `min-width` to #content and #sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

the best would be to use display:flex;

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vIkoG/)**

`display:flex;` BASE CSS example :

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
} 
body {
  display:flex;

  flex-direction:column;
}
main {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
}
aside ,article{
  flex: 2;
}
aside {
  flex:1;
}
```

---

For `display:table`, you would need a work around since `colspan` has no CSS  alternative ,
*this work around can break and allows only  % for the first col width*.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/tEKDi/)**

`display:table` BASE CSS example :

```
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
} 
body {
  display:table;
}
header, main, footer
{
  display:table-row;
}
main {
  height:100%;
}
aside ,article{
  display:table-cell;     
}
aside {
  width:33.5%;
}
header div , footer  div{  
  width:300%;/* = (100% / width of aside ) * 100 */ 
  /* pickup first cell width to scalculate width rescaled , here aside */
}
```

HTML for both examples :

```
<header>
  <div>header</div>
</header>
<main>
  <aside>
    aside
  </aside>
  <article>
    article
  </article>
</main>
<footer>
  <div>footer</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: flex would be best but it's not widely supported yet.

Tables seem to work alternaively. Is there a way to put the footer inside the content?

Comment: if it is a matter to stick footer to main , reset margin and/or border-spacing. you can play with the links as much as you want :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rHpEw/

Comment: @elvista flex would indeed , i'm glad you do not mention IE6 ;)